# Disable ASP.Net button using JS

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to disable a ASP.Net button after the click until the postback is happened.

Following is the code snippet I tried

**.Net**

```
   <asp:Button ID="Approve" runat="server" Text="Approve" 
   OnClick="btnApprove_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return 
   validateApprove();" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>

**JS**

function validateApprove() {
    var disableBtnId = $('#<%=Approve.ClientID%>');
    if(x=1){
        return false; 
    }
    else {
        disableBtnId.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        disableBtnId.css('background-color', '#c1c1c1');
        return true; 
    }
```

The above snippet is disabling the button., but after that control is not going forward i.e., btnApprove_Click is not getting called. Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code.

```
<asp:Button ID="Approve" Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="Approve_Click" OnClientClick="validateApprove(this)" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateApprove(sender) {
        btn = $(sender);
        btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        btn.css('background-color', '#c1c1c1');
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

---

```
if(x=1){return false; }
```

above statement is unreachable as after button click postback state of button will be restored.